# Как вывести блок на печать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас есть скрипт для вывода на печать, но почему-то с некоторых компов после нажатия открывается окно печати но сразу закрывается. В чем проблема?

```
function Popup(data)
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Справочник', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Справочник</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style>tr{border: 1px solid black} td{border: 1px solid black; font-size:10px}</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: меня почему то смущает эта строчка `mywindow.close();` сразу после после того как начинается печать

Comment: нет, дело в том что почему-то не срабатывает print. Если в окне написать window.print() то консоль вернет андейфайн

Comment: попробуйте вызвать закрытие окна после наступления события `afterprint`